# Android User Interaction

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm about to start developing my first Android application, I have been reading through the developer documentation, but am unclear on how user interactions are handled.

As a front end developer, I use alot of css/jquery to create rich  and interactive user interfaces.

I see that Android has it's own version of stylesheets, which seem pretty straight forward, but I am left wondering how I can replace something like js/jquery. Is it possible to use JQ mobile for native Android apps? Is there a replacement to this? Does android's UI handle this?

I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is still possible to heavily leverage your js/jquery skills and create a solid Android application that provides a rich user interface which is primarily js.

This will obviously depend greatly on what kind of application you're writing however if you own a website that delivers rich web content to end users and you'd like to replicate this in an Android application then you should take a look at [webviews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). They should support most of what you're trying to do in js or JQuery and it would be a quick process to mock up a test app to see if it meets you needs. I have run into a few quirks when replicating some interactive d3js visualizations which required extra tweaking before working properly on mobile devices.

I expect these minor issues will be ironed out in the next few releases of Android. [Kitkat is going to include webviews that are based on Chromium](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) which will include an updated version of the javascript engine. Your best bet is to just test it out, the amount of Java code required for a mock application is quite minimal.